# C#: Remove special characters while loading xml having more than 10k of lines to XmlDocument variable

Tags: c#

Below code not working when xml have '&', '<' and '>'.

```
var HugeXmlVariable = TextArea1.Text.ToString();
XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
xDocument.LoadXml(HugeXmlVariable);
```

Things have tried:

```
HugeXmlVariable = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(HugeXmlVariable);

HugeXmlVariable = HugeXmlVariable.ToSTrein().Replace("&", string.Empty).Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").ToString();

HugeXmlVariable = XmlConvert.DecodeName(HugeXmlVariable);
```

Sample Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Bottle>
<Tilt/>
<Colors> Blue & Red </Colors>
<Cap>L<00.001</Cap>
</Bottle>
```

Nothing worked.

Comment: Please provide a small sample of the XML in question. If the XML is invalid then there really is no solution but to fix it. How is the XML being generated?

Comment: If you have any of those unescaped characters your going to have significant problems parsing your XML as its not XML in the first place.

Comment: @DanWilson - Updated xml in the post

Comment: The XML is invalid because `&` in an element value should be `&amp;` and `<` should `&gt;`. You could hack together a method to fix the XML, but the better solution is to correct the source of the invalid XML.

Comment: @DanWilson I can`t correct input xml, I got to fix it, also I tried replacing < with &lt; it fails to load xml. is it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below method

```
    public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == '_')
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The xml is very huge, more than 10k lines. Can`t check each character it`ll take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

**If the XML is invalid, we can read it as text and then parse the replaced text to stream. Then load the valid xml string from stream.**

```
string filepaht="your xml path";
string data=File.ReadAllText(filepath);
Stream newdata=null;

 StreamReader strReader = null;
            try
            {
                //Lookup the encoding. If we not find the specified encoding, we use UTF-8.

               Encoding  messageEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                strReader = new StreamReader(data, messageEncoding);

                // Read the entire message into a string. Not a good idea if you receive largeish messages. Then you ned a bufferen approach
                string msgBodyContentString = strReader.ReadToEnd();

                string[] searchStrings = SearchString.Split(STRING_SEPARATOR.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string[] replaceStrings = ReplaceString.Split(STRING_SEPARATOR.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                for (int index = 0; index <= (searchStrings.Length -1); index++)
                {
                    string oldValue = searchStrings[index];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue))
                    {
                        //default to string empty if we do not have a replace value
                        string newValue = string.Empty;
                        if (index <= replaceStrings.Length - 1)
                            newValue = replaceStrings[index];

                        msgBodyContentString = msgBodyContentString.Replace(Regex.Unescape(oldValue), Regex.Unescape(newValue));
                    }
                }

                // Convert to bytes
                byte[] msgBodyContentBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(msgBodyContentString);

                // Convert the encoding
                byte[] msgBodyContentBytesConverted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, messageEncoding, msgBodyContentBytes);

                // Write new stream back
                newdata = new MemoryStream(msgBodyContentBytesConverted);                                        
            }


var inputXml = XDocument.ReadFrom(newdata);
```